# Is it possible to get the last commit sha of a merge request? GITLAB API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I use the API function [get single Merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr).

Is it possible to find it out the commit sha of the last commit without using [Get single MR commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr-commits)
Just with the get single merge request call?

Comment: Would that be `$.diff_refs.head_sha`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

Get a single commit
Get a specific commit identified by the commit hash or name of a branch or tag.

`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha`

From the GitLab wesite,

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit